# Checking for characters in string in a do...while

Tags: c++

```
do
{
    e=0;
    cout << "Enter input of base " << base << ": ";
    cin >> input;
    for ( i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        if (input[i]=='A')
            value=10;
        else if (input[i]=='B')
            value=11;
        else if (input[i]=='C')
            value=12;
        else if (input[i]=='D')
            value=13;
        else if (input[i]=='E')
            value=14;
        else if (input[i]=='F')
            value=15;
        else
            value=input[i];

        if(value>=base)
        {
            cout << "Invalid input data for your input base!!!" << endl << endl;
            e=1;
        }

    }
}while (e==1);
```

When ever the user key in let's say 101101, and the base is 2, it will output Invalid for 6 times. What's the error?

I tried to use npos, find(), but they didn't work!

Comment: you should use switch case avoiding if..else ladder

Answer (score 2):

Here:

> ```
> value=input[i];
> ```

You seem to be assuming that the value of the character `'0'` is 0 and the value of character `'1'` is 1 (and similarly for other digits). Your assumption is wrong for the character encoding that your system uses. In fact, `'0'` cannot possibly be represented by the value 0, because that is reserved for the null terminator character that designates the end of a character string.

> Thanks But what should i do next?

Subtracting value of a character from another gives you the distance between the representations of those characters (subtracting character from itself gives you 0). Number digit characters are guaranteed to be sequential (0 is immediately before 1 is immediately before 2 ...). Given these axioms, it's easy to prove that subtracting the value of `'0'` from a character gives you the value that you're looking for.

Comment: **Thanks** But what should i do next?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
else
    value=input[i];
```

With:

```
else
    value=input[i] - '0';
```

Because:

**'0' = 0x30 = 48**

Comment: Furthermore, all your code could be optimised to only few lines, but that's out of questions scope.

Comment: Good answer up until the last line - you didn't mention that that's just one possible conformant character coding.  See this [answer to "Converting string to a number"](/a/26227523), for example.